# extract specific data from typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

This is my function of get followers

```
async getFollowingFriend(authUser: User): Promise<FollowingFriendsOutput> {
    try {
        const followers = await this.follow.find({
            where: { follower: authUser },
            relations: ['follower', 'following'],
        });
        console.log(followers);
        return {
            ok: true,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            ok: error,
            error: "You can't get following friend",
        };
    }
}
```

and by doing this, i got data just like this

```
[
Follow {
 id: 35,
 createAt: 2021-04-03T13:28:17.395Z,
 updatedAt: 2021-04-03T13:28:17.395Z,
 follower: User {
   id: 24,
   createAt: 2021-04-02T10:52:30.605Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-04-03T00:47:02.243Z,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  password: '$2b$10$5vcYImjdp3JqBODmeS.3nOsNqy2CBCsjvocV3Z//5Jv0wDp6LImB.',
  gender: 1,
  country: null,
  address: null
},
following: User {
  id: 26,
  createAt: 2021-04-02T10:52:44.638Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-04-02T10:52:44.638Z,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: 'go@go.com',
  password: '$2b$10$.ul2rxR9JV2hA1zFn3HYNekolwkiFZDfLznNwz3LFf6XJE9zEw8Va',
  gender: null,
  country: null,
  address: null
}
]
```

Those are my follow data, but actually this is not my want,
I wanna extract only following data which is locate at the end
I have tried lots of other way, but i couldn't made it
Is there any other method to resolve it?
I'm using typeorm with postgresql and using nestjs framework
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get only the following data, you must remove the follower entity from the relations array:

```
async getFollowingFriend(authUser: User): Promise<FollowingFriendsOutput> {
    try {
        const followers = await this.follow.find({
            where: { follower: authUser },
            relations: ['following'],
        });
        console.log(followers);
        return {
            ok: true,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            ok: error,
            error: "You can't get following friend",
        };
    }
}
```